# min-height not correctly set for ui-page and ui-content

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, height, screen, css

I am working on an HTML5 / JQuery Mobile webapp. It basically shows records from a database and has a multipage set-up. I have a list with records, clicking on a record title takes you to the detail page of that record. And that's where something goes wrong.

After dynamically injecting data (via JSON) into the detail page of a record and refreshing it using `.trigger('create')`, my page height is not set properly. Using Firebug, I can see that JQM adds a `ui-page` class to the `data-role="page"` div and `ui-content` to the `data-role="content"` div, and gives both of them a `min-height` value that does not match the actual screen height. As a result, the `ui-content` div does not fill up the entire page, but only about two third of the page. It then shows a scroll bar in this div for any overflowing content. The lower third of the page stays grey and empty. It actually looks like an old-fashioned frameset with no page loaded in the bottom frame.

Using Firebug, I disabled all assigned styles one by one and discovered that the page only shows properly when I disable `overflow-x: hidden` as set by the `ui-content` class. However... then my fixed header is no longer fixed, but moves up together with the page. I tried adding `min-height: 100%` to the CSS for both `.ui-content` and `.ui-page[style]` (as min-height is hard coded on the div element by JQM), I added `!important`, but no luck.

I am using JQM 1.2.0 Final together with JQuery 1.8.2. The problem occurs on latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, IE9, as well as on Android 2.3.6 after compiling the app using PhoneGap Build. Does anyone recognize this problem? Any suggestions?

The (simplified) code for the detail page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>record details</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="DetailPage" data-role="page" >
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" id="hdr" class="ui-bar-sl" data-tap-toggle="false">
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" style="float:left;margin-left:3px;"><!-- navigation buttons go here --></div>
</div>
<div id="breadcrumb"><!-- dynamically injected breadcrumb goes here --></div>
<div data-role="content">
<div id="RecordDetails"><!-- dynamically injected record data goes here -->
</div>
</div>      
</div>
<script src="js/injectdata.js"></script>
```

The (simplified) code for the data injection:

```
var id = // obtain id from URL-string through a function //
$('#DetailPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
$('#breadcrumb').append('Values from URL-string');
getRecordView(id);
});

function getRecordView(theid) {
$.getJSON('http://www.myserver.net/myscript.php?id=' + theid + '&callback=?', function(data) {
    recorditems = data.items;
    $.each(recorditems, function(index, rc) {
    $('#RecordDetails').append('Here goes all the JSON data').trigger("create");
    });
});
}
```